# AVL Rotations Abbreviations

Tags: terminology, reference-request, binary-trees, avl-trees

I [read](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm) that there are 4 types of rotations:

- Left rotation
- Right rotation
- Left-Right rotation
- Right-Left rotation

What are the corresponding abbreviations: RL,LR,RR,LL? Is there a reference how to rebalance AVL trees?

Comment: In fact, these rotations apply to all kinds of binary search trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please skip [that article at tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm). Instead, read [this article at GeekforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/), which is much better. You may want to check my answer to [another question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99967/avl-tree-rotations-how-to-balance-below-avl-tree-with-imbalance-at-root-node).

The common abbreviations for Left rotation, Right rotation, Left-Right rotation, Right-Left rotation are L, R, LR and RL respectively, as expected. These rotations can be applied to all kinds of binary search trees. For example, they are applicable to red-black trees, too.

Please note that there is [minor confusion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/97555) about the terminologies. However, I would say that more than 9 out of 10 times, you will encounter the mainstream terminologies as explained in that GeekForGeeks article.

A common reference to rebalance AVL trees is the [Wikipedia entry on AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Rebalancing).